# Calling jQuery code periodically

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, dynamic, setinterval

I wrote a `jQuery` script for getting `XML` data. I'd like it to load data regularly i. e. every **10** seconds. I tried to wrap it by a function and then use `setInterval`, but it didn't work. What's the right way to do that?
What I expect is when the XML gets changed, the script will display the change without the user having to refresh the page.

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.get('data.xml', null, function(data) {
        var o;
        $(data).find('city').each(function() {
            o += '<tr><td>' + $(this).find("city_name").text() + '</td></tr>';
            $(this).find("street").each(function(i, e) {
                o += '<tr class="street"><td>' + $(e).find("block").text() + '</td><td>' + $(e).find("number").text() + '</td></tr>';
            });
        });
        $('.data').html(o);
    }, 'xml');
</script>
<table class="data"></table>
```

The code I tried was

```
(function load() {
  //the code above here
})();
load();
setInterval(function(){
  load();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: should work...where's the interval code attempt that didn't work? It's better to figure out why it wasn't working than have someone write it for you

Comment: you can try writing your code inside this `window.setInterval(function(){ 
    //code goes here that will be run every 10 seconds.    
}, 10000);`

Comment: Put your code in a function, and do `setInterval(functionName, 10000)`

Comment: If you want a detailed answer instead of general hints, post the code that you tried so we can show you want you did wrong.

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: @Sushil It seems your solution just delays loading by 10s.

Comment: it does not delay it. the code in the setInterval event gets called every 10 seconds. if you want it to load first and then get called every 10 seconds, then just call the function on page load. see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6j0nr0eg/ and check the console.

Comment: You're right, the error lied elsewhere as I posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution was to use simple JS syntax and to replace

```
(function load() {
})();
```

by

```
function load() {
};
```